# Logic for long number string pattern, adding spaces in php

Tags: php, logic

I have string number:

```
$number = "101011004113511113";
```

And I need to convert this to format like:

```
$pattern = "10 101 1004 1135 11113";
```

I have succeed that with this code:

```
<?php

    $number = "101011004113511113";

    $pattern = "10 101 1004 1135 11113";

    $newNumber = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($number); $i++)
    {
        if ($i == 2)
        {
            $newNumber .= " ";
        }

        if ($i == 5)
        {
            $newNumber .= " ";
        }

        if ($i == 9)
        {
            $newNumber .= " ";
        }

        if ($i == 13)
        {
            $newNumber .= " ";
        }

        $newNumber .= $number[$i];
    }

    echo $newNumber;
```

I would like to know is there a better programming solution for this problem. As I currently learning programming I would like opinion of a experienced programmer, is some better programming solution even necessary.

Comment: what's the rule here ?

Comment: Are the spaces at fixed indexes? Or is there another rule?

Comment: I mean, there is no special rule, I have this number and the rule is ad space like in $pattern.

Comment: That is why I am thinking that there is no better solution for this problem.

Comment: If you already know what you want the end result to look like, why even bother with this?  `$newNumber = $pattern;` no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex pattern to capture the count of numbers you want and then join them by a space:

```
preg_match('/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{5})/',$number, $result);
$result = implode(' ', array_slice($result, 1));
```

This is only the second question where I get to use `vsprintf`:

```
$result = vsprintf("%d%d %d%d%d %d%d%d%d %d%d%d%d%d", str_split($number));
```

Comment: may be the pattern is not steady . it's not generic i think

Comment: I think this is great, the pattern is the same, if they change, I can easily adopt this regex.Nice work.

Comment: Added an alternative, might be easier.